# can something like --rsync-path be done with scp?

Tags: ssh, sudo, rsync, scp, non-root-user

`scp` is handy sometmes because of its -3 feature.  Systems here are configured to disallow root login, however `sudo` is configured to allow certain folks to pass `--rsync-path=sudo\ rsync`.  i'd like to know if something similar is possible to enable admin access via `scp`?  Perhaps some clever `-o` arg, or perhaps somehow invoke `scp` via `ssh`?

Comment: "_Systems here are configured to disallow root login_" is this policy or technical? If technical have you considered adding your key to root's `authorized_keys`? Failing that why not use `rsync` instead of `scp`?

Comment: Not by design. But you can probably misuse the internal kludgeness of `scp`. Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1634882/432690). Still it would be a major hack over a quick and dirty hack (which *IMO* `scp` is) over SSH.

Comment: Worth noting that distros such as RHEL9 are deprecating `scp`, leaving it disabled by default.   Due to various `scp`-related vulnerabilities/risks.  https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/openssh-scp-deprecation-rhel-9-what-you-need-know